# php regex to match text

Tags: php, regex, pcre

I need a php **regex** to match text that is not preceded by the name "Total" of "maximum" case insensitive in the text below.

```
[1]
[1m]
[1mk][1mks]
[1mark]
[1marks]
(1mk) 
12mk

12 mark
13 mark
[Total: 15]
Total: 16 mark
Total 1 mark
Total 12 mark
Total: 9 mark
Total: 10 mark
[Total: 11 marks] Total 6 mark
maximum 5 marks
maximum:5 marks
```

Note: This text is in a one long line.

The regex should match the following

```
[1]
[1m]
[1mk][1mks]
[1mark]
[1marks]
(1mk) 
12mk

12 mark
13 mark
```

I have tried this one but its not working

```
/(?<!Total\:\s|Total\s|maximum\s|maximum\:\s)[\[|\(]?([0-9]{1,2})(\s|(?=marks|mark|mks|mk|m|\]))?(\]|marks|mark|mks|mk|m)[\]|\)]?/i
```

EDIT

[image: Regular expression visualization]

https://www.debuggex.com/r/yNNN_B3iQmGyYWoz

EDIT2
e.g '12 mark' should be returned only is its not "Total[:]\s+ 12 mark" or "maximum[:]\s+12 mark"

Comment: Expected output is according to what rules?

Comment: You might use https://www.debuggex.com/ to try your Regex, it's very helpful to understand what you are writing.

Comment: The regex should match the following

[1]
[1m]
[1mk][1mks]
[1mark]
[1marks]
(1mk) 
12mk

12 mark
13 mark

Comment: @Telewa Yes I know it. But Why? In other word according to what?

Comment: Like i need to get the individual marks from the text, Not the total marks

Comment: Long line like `[1][1m][1mk][1mks][1mark][1marks](1mk) 12mk12 mark13 mark[Total: 15]Total: 16 markTotal 1 markTotal 12 markTotal: 9 markTotal: 10 mark[Total: 11 marks] Total 6 markmaximum 5 marksmaximum:5 marks`? Please clarify.

Comment: No, each of those should be matched if found in the text. The match will probably be an array like array("[1]", "[1mk]") etc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this: `(?:\[?\b(?:Total|maximum):?\s?\d+\s?[^ ]+(*SKIP)(*FAIL))|(\d++\s?[^ )\]]*)`

(Use `i`gnore case.)

## Explanation

### Part 1

- `(?:\[?` Non capturing group that may have a `[`
- `\b` Boundary
- `(?:Total|maximum)` non capturing group matching either literal
- `:?\s?\d+\s?` Maybe a `:` maybe a space, some digits, maybe another space.
- `[^ ]+` A bunch of non spaces.
- `(*SKIP)(*FAIL))|` Plot twist: Anything matching Part 1 FAILS

### Part 2

- This is captured, for real.
- `\d++\s?` digits, maybe followed by a space.
- `[^ )\]]*` And maybe stuff that's not a space, `)`, or `]`.

---

The PHP should look something like this:

```
preg_match_all(
  '/(?:\[?\b(?:Total|maximum):?\s?\d+\s?[^ ]+(*SKIP)(*FAIL))|(\d++\s?[^ )\]]*)/i', 
  "YOUR STRING",
  $matches
);

print_r($matches[0]);
```

Comment: Thanks. But does not work. You could try it here https://www.debuggex.com/ then provide the link if it works

Comment: I didn't see the part where you said it was all one line, but I have fixed it accordingly. it should work now.

Comment: ([\[]?)(Total|maximum)(?:\:)?\s*[0-9]{1,2}(\s)?(marks|mark)?([\]]?)  will select the ones that i do not want. Now please select the others.  Please see here https://www.debuggex.com/r/-KAMhOzikwvMvgo6

Comment: Do you want just the digits? I don't know what you mean by your last comment. Did you try my updated solution?

Comment: I want all else ie: '[1]
[1m]
[1mk][1mks]
[1mark]
[1marks]
(1mk) 
12mk

12 mark
13 mark' in an array

Comment: e.g '12 mark' should be returned only is its not "Total[\:]\s+ 12 mark" or "maximum[\:]\s+12 mark"

Comment: I don't really know PHP, but I think I have the right code. Can you tell me if it works?

Comment: Actually, IT WORKS! my bad. Thanks a million

Answer (score 0):

Actually I would go for the two step solution. First clean up the trashy words by replacing them with this regexp:

```
    (Total:?\s?|maximum:?\s?)
```

Then match all the content you really need is easy:

```
    \[?\(?([0-9]{1,2}\s?marks?|[0-9]{1,2}\s?mk?s?)\)?\]?
```

No idea how to use debuggex.com but I tested all regular expressions in pspad so it definitely works.

Comment: Thanks. However, those trashy words have marks that need to be removed as well. with them. If i could do that, then definitely OK. How do i do that?

Comment: @Telewa The result is exactly like you described it. What marks? Characters like [ ( ) ] ?

Comment: e.g '12 mark' should be returned only is its not "Total[\:]\s+ 12 mark" or "maximum[\:]\s+12 mark"